# Automate Apigee API Proxy Deployment in CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops, pipeline, continuous-deployment, apigee

Is there any recommended method to create and deploy the **Apigee API Proxy Bundle** via a CI/CD pipeline (I'm using Azure DevOps)?

I want to avoid excessive API Proxy Bundles from being created and deployed when there are no changes to be made. I've already tested, and I see that identical bundles still create a new revision.

So far, my own solution is to write a PowerShell script to use [apigeecli](https://github.com/apigee/apigeecli) to download the current bundle and compare it against the `apiproxy` that I have locally in my repo. If it differs, I create and deploy a new API Proxy Bundle.

Has anyone seen anything better?

Comment: Take a look at this [management API](https://apidocs.apigee.com/docs/api-proxies/1/routes/organizations/%7Borg_name%7D/apis/%7Bapi_name%7D/revisions/%7Brevision_number%7D/post). This can help avoid comparing the existing revision against your local copy and also keep the revision count down. The assumption here is that you have your API proxy stored in your version control in case you want to revert to an older revision.

The downside is you would still end up running your pipeline to deploy the proxy even though there are no changes to your proxy.

Comment: On second thought, if you happen to have your proxy code in version control, you can configure your pipeline to trigger deployment only when there is change to the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I have mainly automated with Gitlab but will share my ideas probably may help with your specific case.

So we use version control to manage our apigee repos. I have setup a gitlab pipeline that checks for the diff anytime we push to our repository and only if there are any changes do we redeploy the proxy to Apigee. Normally when the pipeline is triggered, we check if there are any changes to target servers, proxies and shared flows, and if changes are detected, we check the deployed revision and environments.

Through my deployment script, i am able to get a list of these changes and pass them to the pipeline as `CHANGES` variable. This means that only these modified proxies will be deployed.

On my pipeline I could do something like this `git diff --name-only $CI_COMMIT_SHA..$CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA > /changes.txt` and pass the content of the changes file to the `CHANGES` to be deployed.